# Is it a good idea to have the WP installed in a sub-directory?

Tags: security, wordpress, standards

I've been doing a few site builds lately, and I really hate having the root folder so cluttered. I don't want anything impacted on the idea, like SEO, plugin/theme complications, etc.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The physical locations of your files and the URLs to access resources are logically distinct. You can put your application anywhere you want and use your web servers configuration directives to serve them from any URL.

PHP generally is "file based" system. Each URL executes a .php file (usually) and so the distinction above gets a little blurred.

Wordpress is served from a root directory (point of installation) and all things are picked up from there so sub directories are not an issue.